# wpf datagrid aggregating

Tags: wpf, datagrid, aggregation

Is it possible to get aggregation with the standard wpf datagrid, similar to the image below (A Telerik Grid)?  I dont need summing values, just aggregating values according to one or more columns.

[image: Grid Aggregation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) for this, apart from its documentation see linked articles like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542.aspx). To properly display the Groups you may want to specify a [`GroupStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx).